# Redirect single page to HTTPS and the rest to HTTP

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a single WordPress page (`/scheduling/`) to HTTPS, while forcing HTTP on all of the other pages. There are a lot of similar posts on this topic, but my specific use case isn't working for some reason. Thoughts?

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^scheduling/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^scheduling/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The above is properly redirecting all other pages to be redirected to `http` whenever `https` is requested, but isn't doing anything at all for the `scheduling/` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do redirects before default WP rule.
2. Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`.

You can use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /scheduling [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/scheduling [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick question: why won't `REQUEST_URI` work in this context? Doesn't it just return a subset of `THE_REQUEST`? Man, I need to improve my Apache foo...

Comment: Because value of `REQUEST_URI` changes after execution of other rules which is not the case with `THE_REQUEST`.